# Why protected static fields are visible from different class in Java

Tags: java

Here is the following code:

```
package ab:
public class A {
    protected static int var = 10;
    protected int var2 = 20;
}
```

and

```
    package cd;
    public class C extends A {
        A test;

        public C(){
            test = new A();
        }

        void printValues(){
            System.out.println(A.var); //this is perfectly visible
            System.out.println(test.var2); // here I get error saying var2 is not visible
        }
    }
```

I cannot understand why static protected field is accessible though A in different package...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the fact that a `protected` member is accessible from a subclass in any package is widely familiar, I am answering the flip side of your question: Why is the `protected` **instance** field **not** visible to the subclass?

As usual, the place to look for the authoritative answer is the Java Language Specification, in this case [Section 6.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2). I am quoting the example found there because it is much easier to follow than the legalese that precedes it.

**TL;DR:** The best way to think of it is this: `protected` is an *inherited class internal*. From the perspective of all its subclasses, `A.var2` behaves like a *private* member of *each subclass individually* and not a member of the superclass. And all this is in place because `protected` is intended to be used in a class designed for extension, so that the subclasses can access those parts which are considered public API for the extending class, but not for the client of the class.

To complete your series of examples I submit two more:

```
System.out.println(this.var2);      // works---intended use of protected
System.out.println(((A)this).var2); // fails same as your test.var2
```

Food for thought :)

> Example 6.6.2-1. Access to protected Fields, Methods, and Constructors
>
> Consider this example, where the points package declares:
>
> ```
> package points;
> public class Point {
>   protected int x, y;
>   void warp(threePoint.Point3d a) {
>     if (a.z > 0)  // compile-time error: cannot access a.z
>       a.delta(this);
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> and the `threePoint` package declares:
>
> ```
> package threePoint;
> import points.Point;
> public class Point3d extends Point {
>   protected int z;
>   public void delta(Point p) {
>     p.x += this.x;  // compile-time error: cannot access p.x
>     p.y += this.y;  // compile-time error: cannot access p.y
>   }
>   public void delta3d(Point3d q) {
>     q.x += this.x;
>     q.y += this.y;
>     q.z += this.z;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> A compile-time error occurs in the method `delta` here: it cannot access the protected members `x` and `y` of its parameter `p`, because while `Point3d` (the class in which the references to fields `x` and `y` occur) is a subclass of `Point` (the class in which `x` and `y` are declared), it is not involved in the implementation of a `Point` (the type of the parameter `p`). The method `delta3d` can access the protected members of its parameter `q`, because the class `Point3d` is a subclass of `Point` and is involved in the implementation of a `Point3d`.
>
> The method delta could try to cast (§5.5, §15.16) its parameter to be a `Point3d`, but this cast would fail, causing an exception, if the class of p at run time were not `Point3d`.
>
> A compile-time error also occurs in the method `warp`: it cannot access the protected member `z` of its parameter `a`, because while the class `Point` (the class in which the reference to field `z` occurs) is involved in the implementation of a `Point3d` (the type of the parameter `a`), it is not a subclass of `Point3d` (the class in which `z` is declared).

Comment: The tl;dr section explains it the most clearly out of all answers, +1.

Answer (score 2):

Protected means that all subclasses get access to it, and all other classes in the same package. In this case, `C` is a subclass of `A` and thus get access to the fields, regardless of the package it is in.

The subclass `C` can't access a protected field of any other `A` object though, only of `C` objects. So it can access `this.var2`, and if you change `A test;` into `C test;` (and the initialization into `test = new C();`, you are able to access it.

Comment: then why it does not see instance variable. I though extends inherits code.. so I could access it from my C class A... but not protected member of a class..feels like has nothing to do with inheritance here